# How do i add fields from append structure to HCMFAB_LEAVE_REQUEST_CR getway service

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, matlab-app-designer, sap-gateway

According this great manual https://www.mindsetconsulting.com/app-gateway-service-sap-fiori/, I can add append structure field to standard SAP service redefine method ENHANCE_GW_SERVICE_ENTITY_MPC.

What exact method should I use for `HCMFAB_LEAVE_REQUEST_CR` service?

Or give me the way how I can understand what exact method I have redefinition in my case?

Thank you.